# Crystal Reports 2010 for.net deployment error

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have read several answers to this same question but have a couple follow ups.  I have a vb.net 2010 app to deploy onto a server.  This is fine but clicking on the CR report gives the error:Could not load file or assembly crystal decisions.crystalreports.engine version 13.0.2000.0. Can't find file.

The solution I have seen here and elsewhere is to install the CR msi on the target machine.  Here are my questions.

1. I am installing my application onto the network server, do I have to go to every machine that is using this app and install the msi?  I have always been able to attach the necessary CR files to my setup project and no problem installing it on the server.  I realize one cannot do that without merge modules but I am unclear about this msi install.
2. I used to have problems with CR using vb 6.0 because the CR would interfere with other versions of CR used by other applications in various companies.  With .net, the CR files stay within the application space so there is no problem with other programs.  Is that not the case now?  What can I do to have the CR files in my applications file directory as I have had in the past not interfering with anything else?

Maybe the answer is obvious when I run the MSI, but I don't want to take a chance and end up with a serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

I received a response from Crystal that clarifies the installation of cr 2010 for .net in a very simple, clear, step by step way for something that is a very simple operation -- installing CR manually on the target PC.  Since I am not using the merge modules I cannot comment on that procedure.

For development
- VS 2010
- Crystal Reoports for VS 2010 (SP6) install executable.

For deployment three forms of Crystal runtimes are available. Any ONE should be used.

- MSI (Server installer / redistributable)
- MSM (merge modules
- Click once.

See Deployment section in CR for VS .NET SDK developer guide

MSMs are meant to be included in the setup package.
MSI are meant to be manually installed on the target pc.

For your situation (using MSI), install the setup of your app on the target machine and then install CR for VS 2010 SP6 MSI. 32 or 64 bit depending on the target platform of your application (X86 or X64).

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

If using MSM, refer to below doc.

http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Using+Crystal+Reports+for+Visual+Studio+2010+Merge+Modules+%28MSM%29+to+create+a+Setup+project